Is it possible to reliably inject a clickable image or button over an element using JavaScript?
I have a chrome extension that has a function on element focus that changes the border width and color and removes it on element lost focus.
I would like to try and inject an overlay with a clickable button/image to the elements instead of, or in addition to the border changes.
We only support certain element types i.e.: Contenteditable divs, textarea and input[type="text"] and I'm currently targeting them.
I had originally thought that I could just create a CSS class to handle this but haven't been able to figure it out. I have attached an image of what I'm hoping to accomplish. I've tried playing around with insertAdjacentHTML like this;
            el.insertAdjacentHTML(
              "afterbegin",
              '<button id="overlay-button" class="tvce-targetlock-overlay">Test</button>'
            );

and it gets inserted but isn't shown. I tried setting the z-index in case it was behind but it doesn't change anything.
This is what I'm trying to accomplish;

I don't have control of which sites will be accessed so anything I need to do I need to inject. If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated.
Edits based on trial and error
Here is some basic code I'm using to test;
      const validDOMElements =
        "[contenteditable='true'], textarea, input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='search']";

      let supportedElements = document.querySelectorAll(validDOMElements);
      supportedElements.forEach((el) => {
      //This is where I inject the overlay
        el.insertAdjacentHTML(
          "afterend",
         `<button id="${el.id}_button" class="tvce-targetlock-overlay">Test</button>`
        );
        
        el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            el.classList.add("selected_input");
        });


        el.addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
              el.classList.remove("selected_input");
        });
      });
      

The button gets injected but I am having issues getting the alignment done. No doubt due to my poor CSS skills. The buttons are displaying underneath the field. Now, again since I'm injecting into pages that I won't have access to the source so I'll have to inject any CSS class I need. Using a basic class of;
.tvce-targetlock-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
}

I have position the button sort of overlapping the elements on the right but can't control the vertical position.

Please see [ask], then revise your question to put a working demo in a snippet using the editor.

why can't JavaScript interact with the elements on the page?

@RonnieRoyston it can. I just don’t want to make too many changes to pre t breaking any layouts since I don’t know what the various html pages will be structured.

So, why not simply target the elements using CSS selectors and attach click listeners on the elements themselves?

One way is to create a tracking script, that tracks the elements size & positions, and then positions a fixed button to the top right.
Below is an example, you basically call track on an element you want to track, it returns a destructor function, you then call this to untrack.
Try focusing and resizing the TextArea's in the working snippet below to see it working.


function rectEqual(r1, r2) {
  return (
     r1.x === r2.x &&
     r1.y === r2.y &&
     r1.width === r2.width&&
     r1.height === r2.height 
  )
}

function track(e) {
  const bt = document.createElement('button');
  bt.innerText = '';
  bt.style.position = 'fixed';
  bt.style.top = '0px';
  bt.style.left = '0px';
  bt.onmousedown = e => e.preventDefault();
  bt.onclick = (e) => {
    console.log('click');
  }
  let lastRect = {left:0, top:0, width: 0, height:0};
  document.body.appendChild(bt);
  function check() {
    const rect = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rectEqual(rect, lastRect)) return;
    lastRect = rect;
    bt.style.left = `${rect.width + rect.left - 18}px`;
    bt.style.top = `${rect.top - 7}px`;
  }
  check();
  const tm = setInterval(check, 1);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(tm);
    bt.remove();
  }
}


setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('textarea').focus();
}, 100);

let untrack;

document.body.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA') return;
  untrack = track(e.target);
});

document.body.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA') return;  
  untrack();
});
<textarea>Hello</textarea>
<textarea>World</textarea>




That looks pretty amazing and thanks a million for that detailed response. I can't test it out until tomorrow morning. That code snippet is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish though and I can't wait to give it a go.

That is exactly what I wanted. The only issue I ran into was setting an event listener for the button. The button was getting released due to the focusout even firing when the parent element lost focus to the button.
The only was I was able to work around this was to put the untrack() call in a short setTimeout on the focusout and it seems to work OK.  Do you have any other suggestions for the button listener?

@RyanH  Ah yeah, the button gets focus.  You can easily stop this by using preventDefault on mouseDown of the button (ps, this trick also works on mobile).   I've updated the snippet showing this

A million thanks. I didn't think of that.

I guess you can't directly do that but surely you can either create a div with a background image and add event to that div on click or you can do via input tag like this
<html>
<input type="image" src="./yourimage.png" height="20" width="20" >
</html>

